# implied datatype with DIM statement - Breaking change from .net 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm converting a asp.net application from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5

I have loads of inline code like so:

```
    Dim Total = 0

     for each dr as DataRow in dt.Rows
             Total = Total + dr("SumOfAmount")
next
     Response.Write(FormatCurrency(Total,2))
```

Notice that there is no explicit type declaration of the total variable.

This code worked fine under .NET 2.0

Under .NET 3.5, the Total variable is defined as an Integer, therefore the total is being rounded to the nearest dollar on every pass.

I know one solution is just to change

```
     Dim Total = 0
```

to either
         Dim Total as decimal = 0
or
         Dim Total = 0D

However I'd prefer to not have to visit every page in the system looking for this problem.

Is there any site wide, or page wide option I can set the change this behavior back to the way it was under .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you get this behavior because [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is set to On. Setting it to Off will keep the old behavior.

You can change this setting in the project properties page.

Comment: Setting Option Infer to off will make the Total variable an object instead of an integer, according to MSDN. Not sure how that works with math, but it will still not perform as well, nor be as robust as an explicitly typed decimal.

Comment: That worked. I found this setting in web.config, switched it to false and now the math works the way it did previously. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you can get away with making sure Option Strict and Option Explicit are both set to off but this is *A BAD CODING PRACTICE*!

An explicitly typed decimal will perform better than a variant type.

Hopefully, VB.Net 3.5 has done away with allowing the implicit cast.  Obviously they still allow implicit typing, but if making sure all the Options are off doesn't do it, then the only other possibility is that Dim Total = 0.0 might work, which still leaves you looking for every instance in the application.

If turning off all the Options *does* work, you will end up with more robust, better performing code if you turn Option Explicit and Option Strict On and fix the code.